# file_exists method are not working in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

code:

```
<?php 
    $filename = FCPATH.'resources/img/college_logo/'.trim($fetch['college_name']).'.jpg';
    if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>">
<?php 
    }
    else
    {
?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/college_logo/logo_not.jpg">
<?php       
    }
?>
```

[image]

I am new in codeigniter and I want to display image if it exists else display logo not found image but now it only display logo not found. while I echo $filename it show me image path when I put path in url then it show me image but here its not working for me. So, How can I fix this issue ? please help.

Thank You

Comment: `$filename` is an absolute `HTTP` URL?

Comment: make sure file_exists() needs to use a file path on the hard drive, not a URL

Comment: if I am using $filename ='http://localhost/collegescan_ci/resources/img/college_logo/'.trim($fetch['college_name']).'.jpg'; then it show me logo not found why ?

Comment: @omkara maybe it doesn't exist in that local path.

Comment: If you want to use `URL`'s with `file_exists` you need to enable [allow-url-fopen](http://php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: ok now my page look like as I show in my picture plss check once again it show me image but it could not display image.

Comment: In the code you posted, you `echo $filename;`. Use the value displayed in the browser to check if the file really exists on the server on that path. Either it doesn't exist or the webserver cannot read it (or it doesn't have the "execute" right on one of its enclosing directories). Or, more probably, the file is there but the letters case don't match.

Comment: can you check the generated path by inspecting the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you are using file system path if file is found. You should use URL and not absolute system path to present image in browser.

```
<?php 
$filename = 'resources/img/college_logo/'.trim($fetch['college_name']).'.jpg';
if (file_exists(FCPATH.$filename)) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url($filename); ?>">
<?php 
} else {
?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url('resources/img/college_logo/logo_not.jpg'); ?>">
<?php       
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tpojka